# Excel Data Validation List which excludes values already used

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have column A which has some data. Column B has a data validation list dropdown which contains the values in column A. As I select values from the list in Column B (example B1=A, B2=B, B3=C) I'd like the dropdown list to exclude the already used values in that column. So in the screenshot, the dropdown list in B4 should have the (D, E, F, G, H, I, J, and K) values only. A, B, and C have already been used so they should no longer available in the list... So how do I do this?

[image: Example 1]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use helper cells to fill the drop down.

As in:

in Z1 put the following formula:

```
=FILTER(A1:A11,ISERROR(MATCH(A1:A11,B:B,0)),"")
```

[image]

Then in the data validation for the the list you would put `=$Z$1#`

[image]

Now the reference will filter the data as it is used.

[image]

The helper cells can be hidden or on another sheet.  But Data Validation does not allow the direct use of array type formula.

Comment: Its more like diminishing dropdown. Cool Trick!